# How to check if name matches in both items of the array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how you would return the matching value in this example below.

```
const selected = [{
    name: 'Colour group',
  value: 'White',
}, {
    name: 'Style',
  value: 'Cream',
}];

const overrides = [{
    facets: [{
    name: "Colour group",
    values: ["White"]
  }]
}, {
    facets: [{
    test: 'name',
    name: "Colour group",
    values: ["White", "Cream"],
  }]
}, {
    facets: [{
    test: 'name',
    name: "Colour group",
    values: ["White", "test"],
  }]
}, {
    facets: [{
    name: "Colour group",
    values: ["White"]
  }, {
    name: "Style",
    values: ["Cream"]
  }]
}, {
    facets: [{
    name: "Colour group",
    values: ["White"]
  }, {
    name: "Range",
    values: ["Cream"]
  }]
}];
```

So if my selected facets were Colour group and Style I'd then need to match it to the override that also has Colour group and Style and return. Ignoring the one that has Colour group and Range.

I have a JSfiddle with my current progress:
https://jsfiddle.net/61wvubmz/53/

Ideally this will then check if the values are the same and return the override object.

The expected return would be

```
{
    facets: [{
    name: "Colour group",
    values: ["White"]
  }, {
    name: "Style",
    values: ["Cream"]
  }]
}
```

from the override array

Comment: Can you share the expected result? It would make the question clearer.

Comment: indentation could be better too :/

Comment: And what have you tried so far beside posting it on stackoverflow?

Comment: I've tried using a includes, filter and map at the moment. As shown in the JSfiddle linked to in the stack overflow question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const lookfor = selected.map((val) => val.name);
const facets = overrides.filter((o) => {
    let compatible = true;
    lookfor.forEach((lf) => {
        if(!o.facets.find((of) => of.name === lf)){
            compatible = false
        }
    })
    return compatible
})

console.log(facets);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r5nd40z9/4/

Answer (score 0):

```js
const selected = [{
    name: 'Colour group',
    value: 'White',
  },
  {
    name: 'Style',
    value: 'Cream',
  }
];

const overrides = [{
    facets: [{
    name: "Colour group",
    values: ["White"]
  }]
},
{
    facets: [{
    test: 'name',
    name: "Colour group",
    values: ["White", "Cream"],
  }]
}, {
    facets: [{
    test: 'name',
    name: "Colour group",
    values: ["White", "test"],
  }]
}, {
    facets: [{
    name: "Colour group",
    values: ["White"]
  }, {
    name: "Style",
    values: ["Cream"]
  }]
}, {
    facets: [{
    name: "Colour group",
    values: ["White"]
  }, {
    name: "Range",
    values: ["Cream"]
  }]
}];



let result = {}
let output = overrides.filter(o1 => !selected.some(s1 => {
  let r1, r2; 
  r1 = o1.facets[0].name === s1.name;
  (o1.facets.length > 1) ? r2 = o1.facets[1].name === s1.name : ' ';
  r2 ? result = o1 :  ' '
 }));

console.log(result)
```